# Update stock via csv

Tags: import, stock, csv

[image: CSV with data]
How can I update stocks in Dataflow - Profiles?

I have created a csv with the data (see image):

When trying to import it via "Import Product Stocks" then an error shows:

Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: You tried adding the field "type" with values for each row; simple, configurable, etc ?

Comment: No, because the default Export Stock is with only those 4 rows too.

Comment: I just tried it, you are right, the type should not be something mandatory. I can see that the SKUs are numeric, is that the way you have them saved inside Magento ?

Comment: Yes, the sku's are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard error that Magento returns when there is no product with some of the SKUs. If there are 3 SKUs that don't exist in your store - you have to see 3 times this error. Please check each of the SKUs in your CSV file if they actually exist in your store.

You can see `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Adapter/Product.php` -> `public function saveRow`:

```
$productId = $product->getIdBySku($importData['sku']);

if ($productId) {
    $product->load($productId);
} else {
    $productTypes = $this->getProductTypes();
    $productAttributeSets = $this->getProductAttributeSets();

    /**
     * Check product define type
     */
    if (empty($importData['type']) || !isset($productTypes[strtolower($importData['type'])])) {
        $value = isset($importData['type']) ? $importData['type'] : '';
        $message = Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Skip import row, is not valid value "%s" for field "%s"', $value, 'type');
        Mage::throwException($message);
    }
```

If Magento can't get the product ID by SKU - it checks for column `type`, but your CSV hasn't such column, that's why it throws an error.

Comment: So you mean that the skus that are there will be imported? And the ones who ate not will throw an error?

Comment: Yes, exactly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem too.

My SKUs actually existed, and trying to update the products via import/export functionality was throwing me that error.

**Check your SKUs for white spaces!** My store had a `sku` with a white space in the end, while my `.csv` file had the `sku` without white spaces.

As @michael states magento will look for SKU matching - a white space will be enough to not match, of course - then check for type, and throw the error.